# JWT authentication attempt is returning 404

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, reactjs

Hi all i am trying to get authentication token from my rails backend application using react front end. i am getting 404 error, the same thing is working when i am using postman to get the token

React code

```
fetch('http://localhost:3000/authenticate', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: {"email":"abc@mail.com","password":"password"}
})
```

Rails code

```
#app/controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API




  before_action :authenticate_request
     attr_reader :current_user

  before_action :set_headers
     private def authenticate_request
       @current_user = AuthorizeApiRequest.call(request.headers).result
       render json: { error: 'Not Authorized' }, status: 401 unless @current_user
     end

     private def set_headers
      headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
      headers['Access-Control-Expose-Headers'] = 'ETag'
      headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD'
      headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = '*,x-requested-with,Authorization,Content-Type,If-Modified-Since,If-None-Match'
      headers['Access-Control-Max-Age'] = '86400'
    end
   end
```

Please help me to fix this, I am new to both.

Postman screenshot
[image: Postman screenshot]

Comment: Can you add screenshot of postman?

Comment: I have attached the screenshot

Comment: All you need to do is stringify your payload. It should work.

JSON.stringify({"email":"abc@mail.com","password":"password"})

Comment: @remelkabir I tried that but even after doing that I am getting 404 error